# Upgrade SharePoint from 2010 to 2013. How to transform claim-based IDs to windows-based IDs without hardcodely remove "i:0#.w|"

Tags: sharepoint-addin

There is a WPF application. backend is SharePoint 2010 and client is WPF using SharePoint Client Object model.

Now we are in the process to upgrade SharePoint from 2010 to 2013.  The only default authentication is claim-based authentication in SP 2013.  When we run the application to continue to use Windows domain login, all domain IDs have "i:0#.w|" in front of domain IDs.  How to not remove string "i:0#.w|" in hardcode and automatically transform claim-based IDs to Windows-based domain IDs?

I saw someone mentioned to use ClaimsAuthenticationManager.  Is it a right solution.  I wanted to try it but I could not find CliamAuthenticationManager after I added System.Security.Claims.  Why?

Thanks a lot.
YK

Answer (score 0):

[SPClaimProviderManager.ConvertClaimToIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.claims.spclaimprovidermanager.convertclaimtoidentifier%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method converts an identity claim into its original unique identifier.

### SSOM

For Example:

```
var claimMngr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (claimMngr != null)
{
     if (claimMngr.IsEncodedClaim(claimsEncodedUsername))
     {
          var userName = claimMngr.ConvertClaimToIdentifier(claimsEncodedUsername); //returns value in format domain\username
     }
}
```

### CSOM

In case of CSOM API no specific methods are available for encoding/decoding claim into login name and vice versa AFAIK.

**SharePoint Online**

[SharePoint Online Management Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) that comes for SharePoint Online supports encoding/decoding of claim. [Tenant class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.aspx) (`Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly) contains the following method:

[Tenant.DecodeClaim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.decodeclaim.aspx) method - returns a string that represents the decoded claim (the login name) for the specified encoded claim

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a string that represents the decoded claim (the login name) for the specified encoded claim.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">Client Context for Tenant Admin site</param>
/// <param name="encodedLoginName">A string that represents the encoded claim.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string DecodeClaim(ClientRuntimeContext context, string encodedLoginName)
{
    var tenant = new Tenant(context);
    var clientResult = tenant.DecodeClaim(encodedLoginName);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    return clientResult.Value;
}
```

> Note: SharePoint Online is supported only

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My client side uses Client Object Model so I could not use this Server API (SP...) to convert.  Is there a similar can be used in the Client Object Model?  Or do I have to replace "i:0#.w|" which means to hardcode to get Windows domain IDs?

Comment: Ok, the answer has been updated

Comment: Thanks a lot Vadim for the answer.  One more question.  I looked into the articles about SharePoint Online Management Shell and it is about SharePoint Cloud.  Is it ok that I download its dll and add to my WPF/MVVM application (run on client PC)?

Comment: since SharePoint Online Management Shell is a redistributable library and the only requirement i can find is PowerShell 3.0 installed, according to System Requirements spec. So, it could be utilized in WPF applications running on the client OSes where SharePoint is not installed.